# I Need to find the X-Value of the Center of a Circle.

Tags: geometry, circles

How to find the value of the middle of the circle?
We have a circle that lies on the positive x-axis, and it has a radius of 4. Both the lines $y=2x$ and $y=-2x$ touch the circle. What is the x-value of the center of the circle?

Comment: There is more data than needed. There is only one point $C$ on positive $x$-axis, which is 4 units away from line $y=2x$.

Comment: Let $x$ of center is $x_1$, then distance from point $(x,2x)$ to center is $(x-x_1)^2+(2x)^2$. Minimum value of this distance must be equal to square of radius, then minimum of $(x-x_1)^2+(2x)^2-4^2$ is zero, then discriminant of quadratic equation $(x-x_1)^2+(2x)^2-4^2=0$ is zero.

Comment: hey man, is very easy. Check this draw: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVrFJ.png

Answer (score 1):

The answer presented by L F in the comments is perfectly valid and works, but here is another approach I would just like to point out. Let’s just choose the line $y=2x$. The radius of the circle is 4 and it lies on the x-axis, so its equation is:$$(x-c)^2+y^2=16$$$c$ is the x-value of the center. These two equations, of the line we chose and the circle, form a system we can solve. For the sake of brevity, I will not write out all the work, but isolating $y$ and setting the other sides of the equations equal to each other yields:$$2x=\sqrt{16-(x-c)^2}$$Rearranging this gives the quadratic equation:$$5x^2+2xc+c^2-16=0$$Now, we want a single solution for $x$, because the x-values where the circle touches a line is the same- only one. So, we need a double solution, and in the quadratic formula, this means $b^2-4ac$ must be $0$. Setting it equal to $0$ and taking the parts from our quadratic equation gives us:$$4c^2-20c^2+320=0$$And so, we get that:$$c=\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}$$